# Laravel, share image from server to Facebook

Tags: javascript, laravel, image, facebook, share

I have images saved in storage and I want to share them on Facebook. Sharing is working but not the way I tought it would. I will post examples below to show what I get and what I want.

So I get black post that needs to be clicked on to see image, like this:

[image: What I get:]

And I want it to be like this:

[image: What I want:]

HTML:

```
<button onclick="fb()">Facebook</button>
<img src="storage/images/lang/myImage.png" id="imgfb" style="display:none"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>

function fb(){
            var imgsrc=document.getElementById("imgfb").src;
          var fbpopup = window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+encodeURIComponent(imgsrc), "pop", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=no");
          return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: You likely need the full URL, i.e. `https://example.com/storage/images/lang/myImage.png`, in your `imgsrc`. Facebook doesn't know what to do with `storage/images/lang/myImage.png`.

Comment: Which URL are you sharing?

Comment: Facebook actually does know what to do with it cause I can see image when I click on post, it opens the image in new tab.

Comment: You need to set open graph data on that page

Answer (score 3):

You need to set organic tag for image on that link.

On head section of html

```
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{asset('YOUR-IMAGE-LOCATION')}}" />
```

The are also other meta tags available for title and description, do check them on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/